# Why do we consider $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ rather than $|x|$ in solving $xy'=y+2\sqrt{xy}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fractions, homogeneous-equation

Consider this homogeneous differential equation:

$$xy'=y+2\sqrt{xy}$$

We divide the equation by $x$ and write it as $$y'=\frac yx+2\sqrt{\frac yx}$$
Then substitute $v=\frac yx$ and so on.

But how this is valid? I mean first of all we can divide by $x$ if $x\ne0$ and more importantly by dividing second term of RHS by $x$ in fact we did:

$$\frac{\sqrt{xy}}{x}=\frac{\sqrt{xy}}{\sqrt{x^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{xy}{x^2}}=\sqrt{\frac yx}$$

But $x=\sqrt {x^2}$ is true when $x\ge0$ for negative values of $x$ it doesn't work. So my question is how dividing the equation by $x$ is valid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, this is a concern.

However, the equation is singular, the domain is split by the line $x=0$, and restricted by $xy\ge 0$, so that one has to compute solutions in the parts $x<0$ and $x>0$ separately. The solution that you discuss seems to automatically assume that $x>0$, $y\ge 0$.